# strange behavior floats

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is my code

```
#sidebar
{
    width:140px;
    border: solid 3px green;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}


#content
{
    border: solid 3px blue;
    height:400px;
    float:left;

}
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>

<div id="content">Content</div>
```

---

Since the width of the content div is not specified, as expected **it will take up only enough space to display the text inside the div**

Now instead of using the float i use margin like this:

```
#content
{
    border: solid 3px blue;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:160px;

}
```

**The content div will now take up the rest of the width of the browser viewport** even though the width is not specified.

I assume the reason for this is that the content div is inheriting the width attribute of the body tag assigned by the user agent stylesheet. If this is true, my question is **why is isn't the inheritance happening when i am using floats?**

Answer (score 0):

An unspecified `width` on a `div` defaults to `width:100%;`.

You need to specify `width:auto;` to get the effect you want, only being wide enough to contain its content.

```
#content
{
    width  : auto;
    border : solid 3px blue;
    height : 400px;
    float  : left;
}
```